# Why does a decision tree for comparison-based sorting have "at least" n! leaves" rather than exactly n?

Tags: sorting

[image]

The decision tree model can be use for sorting, but I am confused the theorem that it says at least n! leaves but not exactly n! leaves? what other possibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider e.g. [quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), an algorithm which randomly selects pivot elements as part of a comparison-based sort.

Because of this random element, quicksort won't always follow the same decision path even with the same input, so we can end up with more leaves than possible inputs.